# Funciones en Python - Error en Código que no entiendo

Tags: python

Hola Amigos como están? Soy nuevo en la comunidad y un total novato de la programación, estoy aprendiendo Python, y estoy aprendiendo algo que se llama funciones.

En este módulo está este código

```py
def iva():    
    total=int(input('cuanto has gastado?'))
    num = int(input('que tipo de producto has comprado? 1) leche 2) pan 3) leche 4) huevos'))
    if num == 1:
        iv = 6
    elif num == 2:
        iv = 8
    elif num == 3:
        iv = 12
    else:
        iv = 16
iva1 = (total*iv/100)
print ('el impuesto de este producto es:')
print (iva1)
return iva1
iva()
print ('programa terminado')
```

Me salen varias advertencias:

1. total. Me dice que es una variable declarada, pero no usada.
2. iv. Me dice que es una variable declarada, pero no usada.
3. return iva1. outside function

Pero no entiendo que es lo que esta mal y este es uno de los ejemplos del módulo de funciones que estoy estudiando en este curso.

Si alguien me puede echar una mano, estaría agradecido, estoy tratando de entender este tema, y la verdad me ha quedado un poco grande.

Gracias por su ayuda amigos.

Comment: Deberías echarle un ojo a la sintaxis básica de python, en particular, al lugar en el que se dice que **python es sensible al sangrado inicial de las líneas**.

Comment: Voto por cerrarla como `error tipográfico`.

Comment: Así es, es un problema del sangrado de las lineas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Recuerda aceptar y votar las respuestas que te sirvieron! miraste el [tour], pero seria ideal que lo vuelvas a ver para que lo entiendas ;)

Answer (score 1):

El problema son las sangrías, recuerda que python el sensible a las sangrías, tu código debe quedar así:

```
def iva():    
  total=int(input('cuanto has gastado?'))
  num = int(input('que tipo de producto has comprado? 1) leche 2) pan 3) leche 4) huevos'))
  if num == 1:
    iv = 6
  elif num == 2:
    iv = 8
  elif num == 3:
    iv = 12
  else:
    iv = 16
  iva1 = (total*iv/100)
  print ('el impuesto de este producto es:')
  print (iva1)
  return iva1

iva()
print ('programa terminado')
```

Comment: Hola Giovanni mil gracias, tu codigo como está, es perfecto y se ejecuta sin problemas. Mil Gracias. Si, claro está es un tema de sintaxis, de saber identar bien.

Answer (score 1):

primeramente debes tomar en cuenta que al declarar una funcion, ella retorna el valor que desees y lo que esta dentro de esa funcion no puede ser llamado fuera de ella al menos que este en el ambito global, el return lo tienes fuera de la identacion de una funcion, incluyendo las tres lineas anteriores.Tienes un error de sintaxis,esta podría ser otra forma de declarar tu funcion.

```
total=int(input('cuanto has gastado?'))
num = int(input('que tipo de producto has comprado? 1) leche 2) pan 3) leche 4) 
      huevos'))
def iva(num):    

    if num == 1:
        iv = 6
    elif num == 2
        iv = 8
    elif num == 3:
        iv = 12
    else:
        iv = 16

    return iv

iva1 = (total*iva(num)/100)
print ('el impuesto de este producto es:')
print (iva1)

print ('programa terminado')
```

Comment: Loreisiss gracias, tu codigo también funciono bien mil gracias por la corrección.